# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'remoteModules.forEach')

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to test this app :
https://github.com/7kfpun/FinanceReactNative

I use **react-native: 0.26.3**

When the app start, I automaticaly get a

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluation 'remoteModules.forEach')
```

This is one of my first try with react-native and I have no idea how can I solve this problem :/

[image]

Comment: React Native changes pretty quickly, could be a dependency issue. Were you able to locate the line in the JS bundle the error message is referring to? I'm wondering if it's pointing to a module in your `node_modules` folder

Comment: I'm having the same error as well on the latest version of RN. Only happening on Android though.

Comment: Same issue here, tried it on 0.34.1 also on Android...

Comment: @lggy can you please post top level build.gradle file code.

Comment: Hey, how did you solve the issue? Even I am facing the same one.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue too.
My advice is try to delete `node_modules` and install everything again.
It solved my problem. Hope it will help too.

I got this solution by the below.
https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui/issues/26